# ZeroMQ with Qt 5.12 QSocketNotifier Only Fires Once

Tags: linux, qt, sockets, qt5, zeromq

On an Ubuntu 16.04 machine, I am using Python3 with pyzmq to send a base64 ended JPEG through a ZeroMQ PUB/SUB socket to a Qt5 Application. The Qt5 application uses QSocketNotifier to monitor the ZMQ Socket and is supposed to trigger whenever the socket becomes "activated" with more data to read. In my example, the data is completely received on the Qt5 side and the JPEG looks okay - however, the socket notifier only fires once, even though the Python Publisher keeps sending data. If I exit the Python application with ctrl-C, one more instance of the socket notifier activated slot is fired on the Qt5 App side. I want the slot to be fired each time a ZMQ message is sent from Python. I've attached the Python and Qt5 entire apps below. How can I make this work?

```
-------- Header File ------

#ifndef SOCKETRECEIVER_H
#define SOCKETRECEIVER_H

#include <QObject>

// Debug
#include <QDebug>
#include <QDataStream>
#include <QFile>
#include <unistd.h>

// User ZeroMQ Sockets
#include <QSocketNotifier>

// ZeroMQ Includes
#include <zmq.h>

// Debug prints
static void AppDebug(QString message) {
    qDebug() << Q_FUNC_INFO << message;
}

class SocketReceiver : public QObject
{

    Q_OBJECT

public:

    explicit SocketReceiver(QObject *parent = nullptr);
    ~SocketReceiver();

private slots:

    void readZMQData();

private:

    QSocketNotifier *m_SocketNotifier;
    void *m_Context;
    void *m_Subscriber;
    long long int m_RxFrameCounter;
    bool m_DidRXFrame;

signals:

public slots:
};

#endif // SOCKETRECEIVER_H

-------- CCP File ------

#include "socketreceiver.h"

SocketReceiver::SocketReceiver(QObject *parent) : QObject(parent) ,  m_SocketNotifier(nullptr) , m_Context(nullptr) , m_Subscriber(nullptr) , m_RxFrameCounter(0) , m_DidRXFrame(false)
{

    /***** ZMQ *****/

    int major, minor, patch;
    zmq_version (&major, &minor, &patch);

    m_Context = zmq_ctx_new();
    m_Subscriber = zmq_socket (m_Context, ZMQ_SUB);
    int rc = -1;
    unsigned int fd = 0;
    do {

    const char *filter = std::string("").c_str();
    rc = zmq_connect (m_Subscriber, "tcp://localhost:5556");
    rc = zmq_setsockopt (m_Subscriber, ZMQ_SUBSCRIBE,filter, strlen (filter));
    size_t fd_size = sizeof(fd);
    rc = zmq_getsockopt(m_Subscriber,ZMQ_FD,&fd,&fd_size);

    m_SocketNotifier = new QSocketNotifier(fd, QSocketNotifier::Read, this);
    connect(m_SocketNotifier, SIGNAL(activated(int)), this, SLOT(readZMQData()), Qt::DirectConnection);

    }
    while ( rc < 0 );

    AppDebug("Done setting up");

}

SocketReceiver::~SocketReceiver()
{

    zmq_close (this->m_Subscriber);
    zmq_ctx_destroy (this->m_Context);

}

void SocketReceiver::readZMQData()
{

    m_SocketNotifier->setEnabled(false);

    AppDebug("Waiting for next frame...");

    QByteArray newFrame;

    int events = 0;
    std::size_t eventsSize = sizeof(events);
    zmq_getsockopt(m_Subscriber,ZMQ_EVENTS, &events, &eventsSize);
    if(events & ZMQ_POLLIN){

    AppDebug("Read Data...");

    // Receive data from socket
    zmq_msg_t message;
    zmq_msg_init(&message);
    zmq_recvmsg(m_Subscriber, &message, 0);
    size_t size = zmq_msg_size (&message);
    AppDebug(QString("Message Size: %1").arg(size));
    char *string = static_cast<char*>(malloc(size + 1));
    memcpy (string, zmq_msg_data(&message), size);
    zmq_msg_close (&message);
    string [size] = 0;

    if ( string != nullptr ) {

        QByteArray newDecodedData = QByteArray::fromBase64(QByteArray(string));
        newFrame.append(newDecodedData);
        free(string);

        if ( !m_DidRXFrame ) {
            m_DidRXFrame = true;
        }

        if ( m_RxFrameCounter == 0 && m_DidRXFrame ) {

            AppDebug(QString("Debug RX Frame Size: %1").arg(newFrame.size()));
            QFile output("/tmp/abcd.jpeg");
            if ( output.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly) ) {
                output.write(newFrame);
                output.close();
                //sleep(86400);
            }

        }

        m_RxFrameCounter++;

    }

    }

    AppDebug("Setting enabled true...");

    m_SocketNotifier->setEnabled(true);

}
```

------- Python Script ---------

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import zmq
import random
import sys
import time
import base64

context = zmq.Context()
socket = context.socket(zmq.PUB)
socket.bind("tcp://*:5556")

time.sleep(1)
while True:
    f = open("test.jpg",'rb')
    bytes = bytearray(f.read())
    print("Encoded Data Length: %s"%(len(bytes)))
    strng = base64.b64encode(bytes)
    print("Encoded Data Length: %s"%(len(strng)))
    socket.send(strng)
    f.close()
    time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: Just a side-note: I'm not 100% sure about this, but will `const char *filter = std::string("").c_str();` not lead to UB when used later?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use a while since while reading the data you can get another data:

```
int SocketReceiver::events(){
    int events = 0;
    std::size_t eventsSize = sizeof(events);
    zmq_getsockopt(m_Subscriber,ZMQ_EVENTS, &events, &eventsSize);
    return events;
}

void SocketReceiver::readZMQData()
{
    m_SocketNotifier->setEnabled(false);
    while (events() & ZMQ_POLLIN) {
        zmq_msg_t message;
        zmq_msg_init(&message);
        zmq_recvmsg(m_Subscriber, &message, 0);
        size_t size = zmq_msg_size (&message);
        AppDebug(QString("Message Size: %1").arg(size));
        char *string = static_cast<char*>(malloc(size + 1));
        memcpy (string, zmq_msg_data(&message), size);
        zmq_msg_close (&message);
        string [size] = 0;
        if (string) {
            QByteArray frame = QByteArray::fromBase64(QByteArray(string));
            free(string);
            AppDebug(QString("Debug RX Frame Size: %1").arg(frame.size()));
            QFile output("/tmp/abcd.jpeg");
            if ( output.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly) ) {
                output.write(frame);
                output.close();
            }
        }
    }
    m_SocketNotifier->setEnabled(true);
}
```